# KeyListener - do I need to call the keyPressed Method in my main?

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

Here is what's inside my `keyPressed`:

```
public class Movie extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

public static Sprite star1 = new Sprite("Assets/star1.png");
public static Sprite star2 = new Sprite("Assets/star2.png");
public static Sprite star3 = new Sprite("Assets/star3.png");

public void init(){
    this.addKeyListener(this);
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    System.out.println("KEY PRESSED: " + e.getKeyChar());
    animation window = new animation(500, 450); //length , height

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        setFocusable(true);
        Movie.star1.setPosition( Movie.star1.getXposition() -100, 0);
        window.frameFinished();
    }
    else if  (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        setFocusable(true);
        Movie.star1.setPosition( Movie.star1.getXposition() +100, 0);
        window.repaint();
    }

}
```

My object does not move when the arrow keys are pressed.

All I want to know is - is this because I need to call the `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` method in my main? When I do call it, I get an error that states:

> cannot be resolved in a variable

The objects that I want to move are in a giant loop.

Comment: What did you add the listener to?

Comment: have you implemented KeyListener ?

Comment: Not directly related, but you might want to consider using Key Bindings instead. Read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290035/key-bindings-vs-key-listeners-in-java) for a comparison between those and KeyListeners.

Comment: and @immibis what do you mean by what I added listener to? I added it to my class?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Comment: Consider using [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) it solves the issue with focusability that `KeyListener` suffers from

Comment: @bri KeyListeners (and all other listeners) aren't magical and don't do anything by themselves. Typically you call `addKeyListener` on some Swing component, which tells *that component* to call your key listener when a key is pressed. (Note that it's the component that looks for key presses, not the listener). But I see you have `this.addKeyListener(this);` which answers my question (the thing you added the listener to is the window)

Comment: Is your `init` method called?

Comment: what is the "animation" object ? why do you always reassign it with a new keyword ? maybe the star1 changes it's position but you don't refresh the view properly ?!

Comment: @bri Note on coding style: you are mixing up **static** fields (star1, ...) with non-static elements. That is bad style; and will hurt you as soon as you try to extend your example to be more complex. Base rule: try to avoid using static. You need a static main method to start with; but anything else should not be using static.

Comment: @svarog - the animation is from a class in a file called animation.java (yes i know i did not capitalized the 'a'). this creates a window/canvas that pops up and shows the objects.

Comment: @immibis no my init method is never called

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners) on using key bindings instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you never add the key listener to some Swing component, then it will never receive events.

`KeyListener` itself isn't magical and doesn't listen for keypresses. What you do with a `KeyListener` is: you tell some other Swing component (like a window or a textbox) to call your `KeyListener` when a key is pressed. The component is what looks for keypresses, not the listener.

In your case, it looks like you meant to add the key listener to the window, with `this.addKeyListener(this);` (since in your case `this` is both a `KeyListener` and a `JFrame`).

However, if nothing calls your `init` method, then the code inside your `init` method (like any method) never runs, so the key listener doesn't get added to the window, so the window doesn't call it when a key is pressed!

One possible solution would be to make sure to call `init` after creating a new `Movie` (you haven't shown the code where that happens).

Another solution would be to use a constructor, instead of a method, like this:

```
public Movie() {
    this.addKeyListener(this);
}
```

- constructors run when the object is created, so that way, `addKeyListener` will be called whenever a `Movie` object is created, without the creator having to remember to call `init`.