# Keymap, InputMap, ActionMap, KeyListener — choice overload

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, key-bindings, jcomponent

I couldn't find a concise answer about the relationships among all these, so that I can pick up best practices and get going. [`JTextComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html) has:

- The old `addKeyListener(..)`. We write a `KeyListener` with methods that get called on `keyPressed(..)`, `keyTyped(..)`, etc. events, which we can query: `event.getKeyCode()`.
- `addKeymap(..)` and `setKeymap(..)`. A `Keymap` has `addActionForKeyStroke(..)`, which takes a `KeyStroke` (that we can get by calling `KeyStroke`'s static methods specifying the character or key code), and an `Action`, which is an `ActionListener` with bells and whistles.
- `getInputMap(..)` and `getActionMap(..)`. An `InputMap` maps a `KeyStroke` (as above) to a `String`, and the `ActionMap` maps the string to an `Action` (as above). The Java Tutorial [*How to use key bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) talks about that.

These are three redundant ways of attaining the same functionality. Besides comparative advantages/disadvantages, this raises the natural question of how these three mechanisms co-exist? Which ones take priority over others?

Comment: 4 downvotes without a single comment. I interpret this as "you should have spent an hour reading about this instead of asking, since the information is available on the Internet". Well, alright, but not on one concise page. The point of the site is to gather the salient points together, to avoid wading through dozens of irrelevant pages to answer a single question.

Comment: yes, why not, this is public forum with various opinions, part of shadowing commands are implemented in UIManager (standard shortcuts from, you may know fom/in Windows OS)

Answer (score 8):

- `InputMap` + `ActionMap` system was introduced in 1.3 and replaced the older `Keymap` (which was reimplemented using the `InputMap` + `ActionMap` system under the hood, for backwards-compatibility). The new system has a superset of the capabilities of `Keymap`. (From the O'Reilly book *Java Swing* by Loy and Eckstein, on [page 755](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=W3HjIAduQfkC&pg=PT778&lpg=PT778&dq=java%20%22keymap%22%20inputmap%20actionmap&source=bl&ots=603sR6pWMr&sig=A29gJi6aDl4uYnzc8WxZrZr0G8k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV5KzuspDMAhXDJZQKHc4eA4oQ6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q=java%20%22keymap%22%20inputmap%20actionmap&f=false).)
- Therefore, we don't need to worry about `Keymap` for new code.
- The Java Tutorial in [*How to use key bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) doesn't even mention `Keymap`, but it does address `KeyListener`s vs key *bindings* (i.e. the `InputMap` + `ActionMap` facilities):

  - The `KeyListener`s approach takes more work because of issues of focus and component containment hierarchy (which it's unaware of). For example, if we have a table component and a table-cell component contained in it, which has focus, pressing the <kbd>↑</kbd> key will send events to the table cell component, and it will be up to us to relay them to the table (because we want to change the table's currently selected cell).
  - In contrast, key bindings let us specify the binding on the parent component directly: each `JComponent` has **three** `InputMap`s and one `ActionMap`. The input maps are of these types: `JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED`, `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` and `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`. Unlike with listeners, where all of the `KeyListener`s on the focused component *only* are processed in order, with key bindings the event will propagate up the hierarchy (well, a tree I think, as there is only one parent per component) until it finds an action (that hasn't been disabled), which is when it stops. The second type of `InputMap` takes priority over the third during this search.
  - The `KeyListener`s take precedence over the key binding mechanism. While the `KeyListener`s of a component are being processed, one of them may `e.consume()`, and then the event won't reach further `KeyListener`s, nor the key binding hierarchy. Last-added key listeners are processed first.
- So, while the key bindings approach takes a bit more hassle to set up from scratch (you have to give the `Action` a name, and call two methods to bind it to both a `KeyStroke` via an [`InputMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputMap.html) and an [`AbstractAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html) via the [`ActionMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ActionMap.html)), it seems that it should be the first point of call for assigning a function to be called in response to a key press. `KeyListener`s enable you to do more (e.g. exotic key combinations — beyond what `KeyStroke` can handle; and allow earlier access to the key event, with the ability to `e.consume()` it), but key bindings are more convenient, anticipating the basic use cases as they do.

A relevant point (suggested by a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15290035/1143274)) is yet another redundant mechanism for dealing with text components especially: [`DocumentListener`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) and [`DocumentFilter`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html). These are even more convenient and pitfall-proof for when the reason for remapping keys is to control what happens to the text in a text component.

See also: a report about the details of how the key bindings system works from the time when it was introduced, [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20111230135154/http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/special_report/kestrel/keybindings.html).