# KeyListener not detecting key presses

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm trying to make a function that hides a JButton when pressing H. I'm using KeyListener to detect if the "H" button has been pressed. Currently I'm trying to detect any button press. The problem is that nothing is detected and nothing happens. Code Below is the JPanel. Ignore the methods since they do not affect the key detection.

```
    public GamePanel(CardLayout cl, JPanel MainPanel, JFrame frame){
    this.cl = cl;
    this.MainPanel = MainPanel;
    DropColor = DropColorRead();
    this.frame = frame;
    this.frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("asdhuasdiu");

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    });

    super.setFocusable(true);
    super.requestFocusInWindow();

    // Setting the required space for the array "Rain".
    Rain = new JPanel[amount];

    // Allowing random placement of Object on JPanel.
    super.setLayout(null);
    super.setBackground(BackgroundChange());

    Return.addActionListener(this);
    Return.setFont(new Font("Sans-serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    Return.setBackground(Color.white);
    super.add(Return);

    HideHint.setFont(new Font("Sans-serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    HideHint.setBackground(Color.white);

    super.add(HideHint);

    Return.setLocation(50, (frame.getHeight() - 75));
    Return.setSize(200, 30);

    HideHint.setLocation((frame.getWidth() / 2 - 150), (frame.getHeight() - 100));
    HideHint.setSize(300, 30);

    tm.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == Return){
        cl.show(MainPanel, "1");
        tm.stop();
        System.out.println("Rain Paused");
    }

    //First time rendering of the raindrops.
    Generate();

    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        y[i] += v[i];

        //Changing the velocity depending on location and gravity.
        Velocity(i);

        //Brightening the dropcolor the further down.
        ColorChange(i);

        //When a raindrop reaches the bottom of the screen
        Regenerate(i);

        Rain[i].setBackground(NewDropColor[i]);
        Rain[i].setLocation(x[i], y[i]);
    }
    flag = false;
}

public void Generate(){
    if(flag){
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
            Rain[i] = new JPanel();

            NewDropColor[i] = DropColor;
            Rain[i].setBackground(NewDropColor[i]);

            x[i] = (int) (Math.random() * frame.getWidth());       
            y[i] = (int) (Math.random() * -frame.getHeight());
            w[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
            h[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 13);
            v[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
            g[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 150);

            if(h[i] < 7) h[i] += 6;

            if(w[i] < 3) w[i] += 3;

            if(w[i] == 5) w[i] = 4;

            if(v[i] < 3) v[i] += 3;

            if(g[i] < 75) g[i] += 90;

            super.add(Rain[i]);
            Rain[i].setLocation(x[i], y[i]);
            Rain[i].setSize(w[i], h[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Rain Running");
    }
}

public void ColorChange(int i){
    if(y[i] > -frame.getHeight()/10){
        if(y[i] % 10 == 0 || y[i] % 9 == 0){
            if(NewDropColor[i].getRed() < (256 - ColorIncrease) && NewDropColor[i].getGreen() < (256 - ColorIncrease) && NewDropColor[i].getBlue() < (256 - ColorIncrease)){
                NewDropColor[i] = new Color(NewDropColor[i].getRed() + ColorIncrease, NewDropColor[i].getGreen() + ColorIncrease, NewDropColor[i].getBlue() + ColorIncrease);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void Regenerate(int i){
    if(y[i] >= frame.getHeight()){
        x[i] = (int) (Math.random() * frame.getWidth()); 
        v[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 6);

        NewDropColor[i] = DropColor;

        if(v[i] < 3) v[i] += 3;

        y[i] = -10;
    }
}

public void Velocity(int i){
    if(y[i] % g[i] == 0 || y[i] % g[i] == 1 || y[i] % g[i] == 2){
        v[i] += 1;
    }
}

public static int SpeedRead(){
    int Speed = 0;
    try{
        String Ignore;
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Settings.txt")));
        Ignore = file.readLine();
        Ignore = file.readLine();

        Speed = Integer.parseInt(file.readLine());

        file.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Something went wrong loading Settings...");
    }

    return Speed;
}

public static Color DropColorRead(){
    Color DropColor = null;

    try{
        int Red, Green, Blue;
        String Color, Ignore;
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Settings.txt")));
        Ignore = file.readLine();
        Color = file.readLine();

        Red = Integer.parseInt(Color.substring(0, 3));
        Green = Integer.parseInt(Color.substring(4, 7));
        Blue = Integer.parseInt(Color.substring(8, 11));

        DropColor = new Color(Red, Green, Blue);
        file.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Something went wrong loading Settings...");
    }

    return DropColor;
}

public static Color BackgroundChange(){
    Color BackColor = null;

    try{
        int Red, Green, Blue;
        String Color;
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Settings.txt")));
        Color = file.readLine();

        Red = Integer.parseInt(Color.substring(0, 3));
        Green = Integer.parseInt(Color.substring(4, 7));
        Blue = Integer.parseInt(Color.substring(8, 11));

        BackColor = new Color(Red, Green, Blue);
        file.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Something went wrong loading Settings...");
    }

    return BackColor;
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("asdhuasdiu");
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you're setting `super` to be in focus.  For the `KeyListener` to operate properly, the `Component` to which the `KeyListener` is applied must be in focus

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions.

Comment: In my experience, KeyBindings work better. Checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290035/key-bindings-vs-key-listeners-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues.

First, you're adding the `KeyListener` to the `JFrame`, the problem with that is, a `JFrame` is made of a number of other components...

[image: JRootPane]

The next problem is, the `KeyListener` will only respond to key events if:

1. The component is focusable AND
2. The component has keyboard focus

So, when you add other components to the UI, I'm assuming that `Return` and `HideHint` are actually `JButton`s, they can, and often do, steal focus rendering your `KeyListener` useless.

As is almost the case with `KeyListener`, the answer is, don't use it.  No seriously.  If you want more control over when a key event is triggered, then you should use the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which provides not only a more flexible and re-usable API, but provides you with control over how to configure the at what focus level a key event would be triggered

Comment: "The component is focusable" solved my problem.

Comment: @MuhammadKhuzaimaUmair Use key bindings, solve all your issues

Comment: I used all other things, it was working before, then accidentally I removed the `setFocusable(true)` and struggled a lot. I was having only a problem with that part.

Comment: @MuhammadKhuzaimaUmair Key Mappings == no problems; `KeyListener` == lots of strange and unexpected problems

Answer (score 0):

In order for the KeyListener to fire a KeyEvent, you have to be inside the Listened Object (it has to be in focus). If you put other Objects like Buttons or TextFields upon your Frame you block the keyListener on these places.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `KeyListener` to `super` like so:

```
super.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
    //code for listener
});
```

As stated in the comments, the problem you're having is that you're setting your `KeyListener` to a `JFrame` that is being passed into your constructor.  Then you are setting the object that is being constructed to be in focus by calling `super.requestFocusInWindow()`

To allow the `KeyListener` to properly do it's job the `Component` to which the `KeyListener` is attached, must be in focus.