# Set default focus on JButton

Tags: java, swing, focus, jbutton

I have a JButton and a JTextField on a JFrameFrom. I want to enter some data in text field and then when I press enter key, an event occurs without set focus on the button. some thing like Yahoo log-in page. You can enter username and password and without traversing the focus to the  sign-in button, when press enter, sign-in will occur. How could I do this?

Comment: Give the textbox KeyListeners that wait for Enter to be pressed, then execute the button's method.

Comment: @Kon No need for that. Even if there is a need, using `KeyListener` would be dissadvantage.

Comment: ActionListener, nothing more. Already answered  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419667/detect-enter-press-in-jtextfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question good, solution should be easy. Just add `ActionListener` on `JTextField`:

```
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Do stuff...
    }

});
```

When `JTextField` is focused and when you hit an Enter key, event will occur.