# Typing into a JTextField enables a button. Is it wrong to use a KeyListener?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a button called "save changes" that will save any changes if any changes are detected in a `JTextField` component. For now, I assume if the user types anything, then the content has changed.

I am using a KeyListener, but from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419667/detect-enter-press-in-jtextfield) it sounds like using anything other than an `ActionListener` is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a `DocumentListener` to the document of the JTextField. `ActionListener` gets called only when the used presses enter. The advantage of using a document listener is that you can also detect changes made by other means than just by typing.